# How to customise the TOC in Quarto documents?

Tags: r-markdown, quarto, tableofcontents

To make reproducible documents I'm using R & Quarto,but before Quarto I was using Rmarkdown. I think Quarto is much better but there is a thing that I miss from Rmarkdown: the TOC of the documents are prettier than the TOC's from Quarto's documents.

I would like to replicate the style of the TOC in Rmd's documents for Quarto documents. I'm sure it could be done thought css or scss but I couldn't. Any help? thanks
As an example of the type of TOC's from Rmd:[TOC in a rendered Rmd document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oNRQ.png)

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example and what you tried so far :)

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)